# Rails - What is the purpose of params[:commit]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I notice that every time a Rails form is sent to the server, the name of the submit button (usually the string that is displayed on the button) is included in the `params` hash as "commit".

For example (last entry)

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"eZABpBuW7afziDMUJtc1BNEKvGyI7NlTd9+NOYqnMxs=",
 "order"=>{"name"=>"marco",
 "email"=>"marwus@co.xa",
 "phone"=>"0839457382",
 "collection"=>"0",
 "address"=>"18 main street, paarl",
 "city"=>"paarl",
 "country"=>"South Africa",
 "zip"=>"7646",
 "instructions"=>""},
 "terms"=>"on",
 "commit"=>"Next: 3. Payment"}
```

What is the purpose of this?

Is it a result of me formatting my forms incorrectly?

Here is my submit button for this specific example, taken from my `form_for` block

```
<%= f.submit 'Next: 3. Payment', :class => 'right button' %>
```

(The classes `right button` are from [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) forms.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Its a way to discriminate which submit button was pushed. Could be useful if you have very different actions like:

- save a draft
- publish