# What's the function/meaning of the param named "commit" in a rails POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, ujs

What's the function/meaning of the  param named "commit" in a rails POST request?

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"admin@example.com", "password"=>"password", "password_confirmation"=>"password"}, "commit"=>"Register", "controller"=>"users/registrations", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails - What is the purpose of params\[:commit\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382973/rails-what-is-the-purpose-of-paramscommit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `params[:commit]` holds the value of the submit button, which is useful if you're using the same form for multiple actions, like 'Sign up' or 'Sign in' or something along those lines.